# Arcane Mastery vs Spell Penetration which is better to consistently overcome SR?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, feats

Spell penetration gives a +2 to overcome spell resistance.

Arcane Mastery allows you to take 10 on a caster level check to overcome spell resistance.

You have a 55% chance of getting a 10 or higher when rolling a d20.

And most monster SR's are fairly low... which feat will more consistently land?

Answer (score 3):

## What kind of campaign is it?

A monster's [spell resistance](http://dndsrd.net/abilitiesAndConditions.html#spell-resistance) typically equals its [challenge rating](http://dndsrd.net/monsters.html#challenge-rating) +5 or, more often, +10. According to Table 3–2: Encounter Difficulty (*Dungeon Master's Guide* 49), most encounters (80%) will have an encounter level (EL) equal to or less than the four PCs' level. (The table assumes four PCs, all the same level.) With this in mind, **in a typical by-the-book campaign** for a caster whose caster level equals his effective character level, the feat Arcane Mastery (*Complete Arcane* 73) seems to this a player a better—but still not a *great*—choice: with *already* a 55% chance to best the spell resistance of at least 80% creatures encountered, taking 10 on the caster level check to overcome spell resistance means overcoming spell resistance, on average, *all the time.*

However, **in a nonstandard campaign**—as I suspect most are this late in the game's lifecycle—there's no way to know *what* the DM will throw at the PCs. An experienced DM knows when a lower-than-normal EL encounter is a deathtrap and when a higher-than-normal EL encounter is a walk in the park, despite the *DMG*'s guidelines. Further, there's no way to anticipate what kind of challenges will be encountered when playing with a DM who makes the campaign [Nintendo hard](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/NintendoHard). In such cases, a better bet is the feat [Spell Penetration](http://dndsrd.net/featsAll.html#spell-penetration) (*Player's Handbook* 100), if only because, to overcome the tailored or optimized challenges in such DMs' campaigns, *the PCs will need all the bonuses they can get.* Taking the median isn't going to help.

---

***Note:*** This reader recommends neither the feat Arcane Mastery nor the feat Spell Penetration for most casters; they should, instead, be finding ways to increase their caster levels and using spells with entries of Spell Resistance: No *against creatures they identify as possessing huge amounts of spell resistance (or running away… or employing the* Spell Compendium *spell* assay spell resistance *(17) as [this answer](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/115155/8610) suggests). This reader* does *recommend the feat Arcane Mastery to casters (and* especially *warlocks) who have ready access to a number of dispel magic effects as being able to take 10 on caster level checks to dispel magical effects—rather than to overcome spell resistance—is certainly and frequently a thing.*

Answer (score 2):

\$\DeclareMathOperator{\vs}{vs.}\$Here is a table of how much better (the ratio of the success rate with the feat to the success rate without it, expressed as a percentage—100% means the feat does not change your success rate) each feat is. \$SR - CL\$ is the target spell resistance minus your caster level (before either feat), that is, the roll you need on the d20 to succeed.

| *SR* − *CL* | Arcane Mastery | Spell Penetration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ≥23 | N/A¹ | N/A² |
| 22 | N/A¹ | ∞ (10% vs. 0%) |
| 21 | N/A¹ | ∞ (5% vs. 0%) |
| 20 | N/A¹ | 300% |
| 19 | N/A¹ | 200% |
| 18 | N/A¹ | 167% |
| 17 | N/A¹ | 150% |
| 16 | N/A¹ | 140% |
| 15 | N/A¹ | 133% |
| 14 | N/A¹ | 128% |
| 13 | N/A¹ | 125% |
| 12 | N/A¹ | 122% |
| 11 | N/A¹ | 120% |
| 10 | 200%* | 118% |
| 9 | 181%* | 117% |
| 8 | 154%* | 115% |
| 7 | 143%* | 114% |
| 6 | 133%* | 113% |
| 5 | 125%* | 113% |
| 4 | 118%* | 112% |
| 3 | 111%* | 111%* |
| 2 | 105%* | 105%* |
| ≤1 | 100%† | 100%† |

1. <sub>For *SR* − *CL* greater than 10, you cannot use Arcane Mastery (or, doing so guarantees failure), so it has no effect on your success rate.</sub>
2. <sub>For *SR* − *CL* greater than or equal to 23, you cannot succeed even with Spell Penetration, so the feat has no effect on your success rate.</sub>

* <sub>Guaranteed success with the feat.</sub>

† <sub>Guaranteed success even without the feat.</sub>

So Spell Penetration helps in a lot more situations, and helps more in its best use-cases. But Arcane Mastery *guarantees* success against far more creatures, and creatures with SR high enough to really put Spell Penetration to good use, are really creatures *you really don’t want to be checking spell resistance against.* Even though Spell Penetration literally gives an infinitely-greater chance of success if the SR was 21 or 22 higher than your CL, you are still left with only a 10% or 5% chance of actually beating the SR with Spell Penetration. Something with SR that high is far too dangerous to take odds like that—you need to use SR: No spells, or probably better, running away.

Which is really the big problem with *either* approach to SR: you are investing a huge amount (a feat) into beating SR, when you really want to *not have to*. There are a lot of alternatives for spellcasters to avoid having to actually roll against SR at all, and they are often very good.

And if you really want to use an SR: Yes spell in such a situation, these feats aren’t the best answer anyway. That would be *assay spell resistance* from *Spell Compendium*—that applies a whopping −10 penalty to a target’s SR. If you have SR: Yes spells that you want to be able to use, prepare a few copies of *assay spell resistance*, and be done with it.

All that said, Arcane Mastery isn’t a bad feat for other purposes, perhaps most notably *dispel magic*. If you must pick one of them, pick that one just because it does more than just SR.